# Windows 10 theme resources in XAML and in code

Tags: c#, xaml

If I create a grid in XAML with a themed background:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
```

and then change its theme in code:

```
MyGrid.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
```

the grid background color changes from white to black, exactly as expected.

However, if I create a grid in XAML without specifying its background:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
```

and then execute this code:

```
MyGrid.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
MyGrid.Background = MyGrid.Resources["ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush"] as Brush;
```

the background does not change to black. In other words, when accessed in code, theme resources do not seem to depend on the current requested theme of the element.

Does anybody know how to access theme resources in code so that their values properly reflect the current requested theme of an element?

Comment: I have tried in several ways but nothing. I do not know how the XAML ThemeResource goes by codebehind, it is a really strange 'binding'. It might be a way to get the Dark dictionary but I couldn't